# C++ - multiple inheritance for dynamic casting

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`. I have a data loader that loads data from file and return them as `Foo` or `Bar`.

Currently I have the solution as:

```
struct Foo { 
  std::vector<Foo> Filter() {
     //do something with data and return new Foo's
  }
  std::vector<int> data; 
}

struct Bar : protected Foo {
  std::vector<Bar> Filter() {
     //do something with data and return new Bar's
  }
}

template <typename T>
DataLoader<T> { 
    .... 
    T & Get() { ... }
}
```

where `T` is either `Foo` or `Bar`.

The problem with this solution is that I cannot dynamically choose to return `Foo` or `Bar`. I have to reload data. Ue of virtual method is not working, since `Filter` has different return types. Also, making inheritance public is not an option, because in that case I could do `Foo f = Bar();` which I dont want to enable.

I have come up with a solution using multiple inheritance. However, I am not sure if it is correct or it would produce undefined-behaviour.

I have added private class to `DataLoader`:

```
struct FooBarStorage : virtual public Foo, public Bar {}
```

and changed inheritance in `Bar` to `struct Bar : virtual protected Foo`.

Now I can have non-templated `DataLoader`:

```
class DataLoader {

  template <typename T> T & Get() { ... }
}
```

and specialise `Get` to return `Bar &` or `Foo &`. The advantage is, I can load data only once and decide what to return in runtime. With a previous solution, data were loaded with a given type (`Foo` or `Bar`) and I was not able to change the type.

Is this a possible working solution or would it produce undefined-behaviour / other problems / performance impacts?

Comment: _"Is this a possible working solution"_ 1st what came to my mind reading through your question. I believe the `virtual` inheritance is exactly to solve that specific purpose.

Comment: Another interesting land to explore is what could be done with `virtual` inheritance in combination with the CRTP. All in all, it's about function call dispatching to the right target instance, no?